# How to prevent setting the fontsize to tiny from reducing the size of the table caption when using longtable

Tags: captions, longtable, fontsize

I have a very large table of results. It spans over two pages using the `longtable` package. To reduce the size of the table I have set the font size to `\tiny`. However, as a `longtable` doesn't exist within a float, it makes the table ID (eg "Table 1") before the table caption tiny also.

Below is a working example of my code:

```
\tiny
    \begin{longtable}{llllll}
    \caption{\normalsize{This is the caption.}}\\
\hline
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 & column 4 & column 5 \\ \hline
blah & blah & blah & blah & blah \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

How do I produce a longtable with tiny text in the cells but normal sizing for the table ID/number?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what is table ID? is this caption? caption font is determined  with caption set up and should be independent from fonts used in table. for clarifying question please provide small but complete document beginning with `\documentclas...` and ending with `\endbdocument}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typesetting of the `\caption` under [`longtable`](//ctan.org/pkg/longtable) is defined within `\LT@makecaption` and doesn't follow the same protocols of the regular placement of `\caption`s within floats, since a `longtable` doesn't float.

You can patch `\LT@makecaption` to use `\normalsize` for setting the caption (using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\LT@makecaption}% <cmd>
  {\sbox}% <search>
  {\normalsize\sbox}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tiny
\begin{longtable}{ *{6}{l} }
  \caption{This is the caption.} \\
  \hline
  column 1 & column 2 & column 3 & column 4 & column 5 \\
  \hline
  blah & blah & blah & blah & blah \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The other - more preferred - option is to use [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption):

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}
```

Comment: ...and if the documentclass used is incompatible to the `caption` package, there is a 3rd option: `\usepackage{ltcaption}\renewcommand\CaptionLabelFont{\normalsize}\renewcommand\CaptionTextFont{\normalsize}`. (This works only if the `caption` package is *not* loaded.)